# Megamenu, submenu to display from top

Tags: jquery, html, css, opencart

Using Megamenu at Opencart 2, when we have a lot of subcategories, there's a small problem when hover over to the bottom categories. Its subcategories will display at an even lower position, which is not great for user friendliness.

[image: Default]

Is it possible to achieve like the below concept picture, where the submenu display up from top again, which align with the first level menu column by CSS?

[image: Concept]

Website URL: http://mytools.my

Comment: Here, this is possible. but, I think, here, You not should to this. because, It will create issue(you can try go to subcategory. So, menu dropdowb will hide.). Exmaple - when, You will go 5th Main categories. but, if, sub categories is available only 2 to 4. so, You can not move your mouse on subcategories from main category. Menu dorp down will be hide.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `div#top` seems to be of a fixed height, you could set the `ul.active`'s position to `fixed` instead of `absolute`, and using jQuery to see how much the user has scrolled, set the `top` value of the `ul.active` accordingly (you can use .scrollTop(), I guess)

Or you could just remove the `position: relative` from the mainmenu list items and set their width also to be the same as the submenus'